# Chart filtered by parameter Report Builder

Tags: sharepoint, parameters, charts, reportbuilder3.0

I need to filter data in a chart using a parameter. To be more specific, the user enter a parameter corresponding to a production Line (Line 1,Line 2, Line 3).
When he made his choice, a table appears with informations for this specific line (Line, Machine, Time). The time column refers to the Down Time of the machine (entered by another operator).

I displayed a chart that has to be dynamic and has to show the Machines (of the specified line) as X axis and their stop time as Y axis.
The problem is that the chart doesn't display the machines of the specified line (In the parameter) but all the lines's machines.
I have to put a filter of change the expression of the X axis but I don't know what to put for the expression.
The lines, machines, times, come from a SharePoint List.
If you have any idea...

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution: I added a filter to the X axis "Machine" that says "Lines"=Parameter. and it displays the right machines.

Answer (score 0):

You should just be able to go to DataSet Properties, Filters and then add Parameters!.Value = Fields!Machine.Value, and that should cause the chart to just display for rows where the Machine field matches your parameter value

Comment: Doesn't work, because my parameter's availiable values comes from the same dataset that is used for the table and the chart. It says that forward dependencies are not valid. 
I have another filter depending on the parameter that works. Indeed, the table only shows the Line I choose in the parameter but the chart doesn't care.. haha

Comment: Found the solution:

I added a filter to the X axis "Machine" that says "Lines"=Parameter. and it displays the right machines.